# Setup Android for kids?

Tags: security, protected-apps

How to setup Android so that the phone app is completely usable without a pin, but all others apps need unlocking

Answer (score 0):

First of all, question is very nice.
You can do whatever you want for your kids simply by creating another account like a Guest.

> But, Google already launched their app called "[Google Family
>   Links](https://families.google.com/familylink/)". Here you can control whatever apps you want your kids to
>   use and also how long they've access to the apps. You also track their
>   usage by your phone and can lock (Blocking them from more usage) the
>   phone.

Comment: Unfortunately Google family doesn't work across countries and in some countries

Comment: Don't worry about it. You still should use it without any hestitance. You've to donload it from third party websites like APKMirror. And once you install it. Boom! You're ready to go!